# How to export an individual bookmark folder in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

In my bookmarks window I have two to three folders like `asp.net`, `jquery` and `sql server`. How do I export the `jquery` folder only from Google Chrome?

Comment: Chendur - it would be helpful to mark the second answer as the accepted one. It is more useful today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Data Liberation Front](http://www.dataliberation.org/google/chrome-bookmarks) has a short statement about this: It seems to be possible to export the bookmarks to Google Docs. Perhaps post-processing is easier there. However, I haven't tried that.

Comment: In recent versions of Google Chrome it is not possible to export bookmarks to Google Docs.

Comment: Make sure to check out [the answer below](https://superuser.com/a/593588/167304) for a solution that actually works ;)

Comment: See working answer below, but for those curious about dataliberation.org (as I was), it appears to have been taken down in 2014, and now redirects to a google support answer. I assume the info is obsolete, but the latest archive.org snapshot I found is https://web.archive.org/web/20140123094034/http://www.dataliberation.org/, and this November 2013 snapshot has a working link to the gmail section: https://web.archive.org/web/20131119045301/http://www.dataliberation.org/.

Comment: Thank you for unearthing this info! Yes, unfortunately the data liberation front ceased to exist. It was a cool initiative during Google’s “don’t be evil” years.

Answer (score 72):

Create a new user in Chrome, then drag your desired bookmarks to the bookmarks of the new user (make sure you enabled bookmarks bars being shown for two users).

Next, export bookmarks from the new user. Voilà!

Comment: I think this is the most elegant and user friendly way

Comment: I like this solution best. But how to enable bookmarks bar for 2 users?

Comment: How to enable the bookmarks bar: go to the Chrome menu -> Bookmarks -> Show Bookmarks Bar. Ctrl-Shift-B on Windows.

Comment: @RandySkretka I think I found out what was meant by `bookmarks bar shown for two users`: When you select a second user in chrome, it opens a fresh new window for that user, without closing the original window. So you should keep both windows side by side, and make sure both windows have bookmarks bar enabled. Then you can drag-n-drop bookmarks (or bookmark folders) from one window to the other.

Comment: I wish this could be marked as the answer. The accepted answer is not at all helpful.

Comment: Spelling out the steps in more detail for today's users:
1) Create another user profile (settings > People/Manage other people) > ADD PERSON. That will open a new browser window in that new profile.
2) Open bookmark manager in both previous and new windows.
3) Drag and drop any desired folders from previous to new, and they will be copied. 
4) When you are all set, click the three dot stack in the upper right of the bookmark manager in the new window and choose Export bookmarks. You will get an export file with only the bookmarks you dragged in.

Comment: Honestly, the easiest way to get the job done. It's a strange way, but it works, and I can't argue with that.

Comment: This led me to a solution of using an existing Chrome profile that I have setup for JS debugging. Copy -> Paste -> Export -> Done.

Comment: For BRAVE browser (brave doesn't have "users"): `1.` Create a new profile (triple-bar > `Create a new profile`), `2.` open bookmarks (ctrl shift o) in both windows, `3.` drag and drop (or copy/paste) required folders, `4.` export as normal (from the new profile). You can remove the new profile (profile avatar button > cog > triple-dot > delete) or keep it for this purpose. I like to store research bookmarks for a project in the project's directory, and this works well. I can browse the bookmarks file in lynx or w3m, or import to a GUI browser.

Comment: Perfect! The most classy solution

Answer (score 16):

1. Open the bookmark manager (bookmarks menu drop down)
2. Pare down until you open the folder you want to export with the contents shown on the right side window
3. click *once* on the first listing, so as to select it. ctrl-A to select all in the right side window, ctrl-C to copy all of the contents.
4. Open a new file in your text editor*
5. Paste (ctr-v) links into text document. Save as rich text.
6. If you would prefer in word, copy from text editor and paste in word.

*This method provides the title of the pages you saved, with the URL link in it. If you ONLY want the URL, instead of opening a text editor at step 4, open a WORD doc. Paste (ctrl-v) there and you will only have a list of URLs.

Comment: This is the best and simplest answer I guess. Thank you.

Comment: Nice but in this way it doesn't export subfolders

Comment: Not sure about Chrome, but for Firefox all the bookmarks, including those in subfolders, will get copied as one big flat list of URLs.

Comment: Note that pasting into Google Docs may not work - but just paste into something else, like TextEdit, and it will be ok. Then copy from there into Google docs :D !

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't seem possible by now. You can export all of your bookmarks then edit with a text editor and delete unwanted. If you temporarily seperate your bookmarks into groups before it's easier to do.

Comment: Export all your bookmarks as HTML, import them into a browser with a better bookmark manager (such as Firefox), then you can export a single folder of bookmarks.

Comment: It is possible now.

Comment: @Sathya♦ how to ?

Comment: @Athimannil I explain it [in my answer](http://superuser.com/a/758788/4377)

Answer (score 8):

Move the folder you want to export to the left end of the bookmark bar. Export all bookmarks to file. Open the file in notepad. Find the bookmark that appears last in the folder you are trying to export. Delete everything after that bookmark. Save the file.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit (18-07-01):** updated so it works in chrome's latest bookmarks (chrome v67).

You can use this JS folder-exporter I hacked together.

> Note: this may break any time Chrome changes the underlying HTML of their bookmarks manager.

#### Manual workflow

1. Go to bookmarks, and open your desired folder
2. Open Console <kbd>F12</kbd>
3. Paste this:

   ```
   var items = document.querySelectorAll('body > bookmarks-app::shadow bookmarks-list::shadow iron-list bookmarks-item');
   var ret = [];
   var str = '';

   // store to temp array
   Array.prototype.forEach.call( items, function ( elem ) {
     var label = elem.querySelectorAll('::shadow #website-title')[0].textContent.trim();
     var url = elem.querySelectorAll('::shadow #website-url')[0].textContent.trim();
     ret.push( [ label, url ] );
   }); 

   // style the output here
   ret.forEach(function( item ) {
     str += item[0] + '\r\n\t' + item[1] + '\r\n';
   });

   // print to console
   console.log(str);
   // or copy to clipboard
   copy(str);
   ```
4. Copy output from console

Or you can have the output download as a file using e.g. [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21177212/927631) (make sure you use it *after* you've run the previous one):

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('body > bookmarks-app::shadow bookmarks-list::shadow iron-list bookmarks-item');
var ret = [];
var str = '';

// store to temp array
Array.prototype.forEach.call( items, function ( elem ) {
  var label = elem.querySelectorAll('::shadow #website-title')[0].textContent.trim();
  var url = elem.querySelectorAll('::shadow #website-url')[0].textContent.trim();
  ret.push( [ label, url ] );
}); 

// style the output here
ret.forEach(function( item ) {
  str += item[0] + '\r\n\t' + item[1] + '\r\n';
});

function downloadFile ( filename, data ) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = filename;
    a.href = 'data:,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}

var d = new Date();
var month = (d.getMonth() + '').length === 1 ? '0' + d.getMonth() : d.getMonth();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var date = d.getDate();
var dateStr = year + '-' + month + '-' + date;

downloadFile( 'bookmarks-'+ dateStr +'.txt', str );
```

#### Bookmarklet

<strike>Or put this bookmarklet to your bookmarks-bar and click it any time you're in your folder you want to export (it's the same code as above, including the save-as-file).</strike>

**Edit (18-07-01):** it seems chrome no longer allows execution of bookmarklets (javascript) in bookmarks tab.

You can still copy and paste this into console (f12) manually:

```
javascript:function downloadFile(t,e){var o=document.createElement("a");o.download=t,o.href="data:,"+encodeURIComponent(e),document.body.appendChild(o),o.click(),document.body.removeChild(o)}var items=document.querySelectorAll("body > bookmarks-app::shadow bookmarks-list::shadow iron-list bookmarks-item"),ret=[],str="";Array.prototype.forEach.call(items,function(t){var e=t.querySelectorAll("::shadow #website-title")[0].textContent.trim(),o=t.querySelectorAll("::shadow #website-url")[0].textContent.trim();ret.push([e,o])}),ret.forEach(function(t){str+=t[0]+"\r\n\t"+t[1]+"\r\n"});var d=new Date,month=1===(d.getMonth()+"").length?"0"+d.getMonth():d.getMonth();downloadFile("bookmarks-"+d.getFullYear()+"-"+month+"-"+d.getDate()+".txt",str);
```

---

The above code exports e.g. this folder,

[image]

into following output:

```
How to export an individual bookmark folder in Google Chrome? - Super User
    http://superuser.com/questions/128242/how-to-export-an-individual-bookmark-folder-in-google-chrome
data URIs - HTTP | MDN
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs
```

You can style the output as you wish in the `ret.forEach` loop.

Comment: Nice, I was just about to do this but I saw you had done it.  Thanks!

Comment: With the bookmarklet option I occasionally misclick and it downloads an empty text file.  I just updated it to check the window.location.url and alert if it's not on the chrome bookmarks page.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Should be the accepted answer...

Answer (score 4):

1. Delete all the folders you don't want to Export.
2. Now, Export. It will only export the one folder left.
3. Once done, Ctrl+z on bookmarks manager, and you'll get back all the deleted bookmark groups back.
4. Be happy and dance.

Answer (score 4):

Fastest and easiest way:

1. Export all bookmarks into a file.
2. Create a new user in Chrome
3. Import bookmarks from a file to the new user and delete unnecessary folders
4. Export and be happy!

This answer is similar to "delete folders, export and restore with ctrl-z", but is more secure and loss-free.

Answer (score 1):

1. Export your bookmarks as normal
2. Get the FREE OpenOffice Writer
3. Open your bookmarks HTML-file in Writer
4. Delete, move, change as normal. Be aware of end and starting points of HEADINGS etc
5. File > Save as a name of your choice. OpenOffice understands that you want a HTML-file

Comment: worked best for me!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Google Chrome
2. Navigate to the bookmarks manager
3. Export the html file
4. Delete all the folders/bookmarks you don't want in your save file
5. Export the html file - with a new (different) name
6. Import the original file to restore everything
   Simple, elegant and hassle free.

Answer (score 0):

I found no way but to export Bookmarks into .html file and then open it (using chrome). Then I have to hand-pick all required bookmarks and copy them.

However I found that the following preparation step simplifies the above process:

1. Enter Bookmark Manager - you will see "Bookmarks bar" with subfolders
2. In the "Bookmarks bar" create a new sub-folder, say "Export", and position it as the 1st (top-most) sub-folder in the "Bookmarks bar" .

When you export Bookmarks - this subfolder will be the 1st (the top-most) in the exported file.

3. Withing Bookmark Manager copy required items into the "Export" one.
4. Presto.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the following work-around:

- Export all bookmarks to html document.
- Edit the file (using [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/) or any other html editor) and delete all unwanted parts.
- Save it and import it again.

You are done. :) woopey

Answer (score 0):

Switch to new chrome user, then drag and drop bookmark folder to new user bookmark.
After done, export it from new chrome user.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select "Bookmarks Manager", then select "Organize".
2. Select "Export bookmarks to HTML file...". Name your file and save on desktop.
3. The file saved will have ALL bookmarks.
4. Open this file, highlight only the bookmarks you want, and copy and paste on a MS Word document **BUT save this document as an HTML file**. Make sure you remove "docx", and change the extension to "html" after the file name. Make sure, under "Save as type:" you select "Web page (*.htm;*.html)".
5. Now you have an html file with only the bookmarks you want. You can now email this anywhere, and import the bookmarks from this file into the browser by selecting "Import bookmarks from HTML file..." under "Organize".

I don't think you can get any simpler.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Chrome extension for that ...

- [Export Selective Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-selective-bookmark/ahgbiciilcpclcekhegbhofljoolnfei)

It allows you to select and export any subset of your bookmarks. The tree control will allow you to select any number of folders or bookmarks to include or exclude from your export.

When you import, folders will appear under the "Bookmarks Bar" parent folder from which you can drag drop imported subfolder. If you're confident editing HTML, you edit the exported HTML file to remove the "Bookmarks Bar" parent folder.

[image: select and export any subset of your bookmarks]

Answer (score 0):

Modified from @dwelle's answer because [::shadow was deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/remove-shadow-piercing/). Newer versions of chrome will give an error.
(Have tested chrome v96 version)

1. Go to bookmarks, and open your desired folder
2. Open Console <kbd>F12</kbd>
3. Paste this:

   ```
    var items = document.querySelector("body > bookmarks-app").shadowRoot.querySelector("bookmarks-list").shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("iron-list bookmarks-item:not([hidden])")
    var ret = [];
    var str = '';

    // store to temp array
    Array.prototype.forEach.call( items, function ( elem ) {
    var label = elem.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('#website-title')[0].textContent.trim();
    var url = elem.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('#website-url')[0].textContent.trim();
    ret.push( [ label, url ] );
    }); 

    // style the output here
    ret.forEach(function( item ) {
    str += item[0] + '\r\n\t' + item[1] + '\r\n';
    });

    // print to console
    console.log(str);
    // or copy to clipboard
    copy(str);
   ```

download variable `str` as a file

```
function downloadFile ( filename, data ) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = filename;
    a.href = 'data:,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}

var d = new Date();
var month = (d.getMonth() + '').length === 1 ? '0' + d.getMonth() : d.getMonth();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var date = d.getDate();
var dateStr = year + '-' + month + '-' + date;

downloadFile( 'bookmarks-'+ dateStr +'.txt', str );
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer has not been given yet and is extremely easy.

IF your goal is to move a specific folder with bookmarks from one Chrome instance to another (thus exporting and then importing) all you need to do is open the bookmark manager on both instances. Go to the specific folder and press control+C to copy it. Go to the other instance and press control+V to paste it. Even though the option does not appear when right clicking, it does work flawlessly. You can do this with individual bookmarks, or multiple selected (with shift or control) and even entire folders.

ps. for this to work in case of a VM or similar, make sure you have shared clipboard enabled.

Answer (score -1):

1. Export all bookmarks, and view the source code of the created html file
2. Scroll down to the folder you want to copy
3. Copy the source code you want
4. Open a new notepad txt file and paste the code
5. Save the file in HTML format

Answer (score -1):

To save your Chrome bookmarks as a .doc file or .pdf file:
In Chrome Export your bookmarks as an HTML file.
In Firefox, open that HTML file that you just saved.
CTRL 'A' to select all then open WORD
In a new document CTRL 'V' to paste. 
At the bottom of the text that you have just pasted is a small box with a clipboard inside and the word (CTRL).
Click on the small downward pointing chevron and then select "Keep source formatting (K)
Now save as a Word document or a PDF.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Answer (score -2):

Open Bookmarks Manager in Chrome by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (or by entering *chrome://bookmarks* in the Address Bar/Omnibox)

[image: Chrome Bookmark Manager image]

Select the desired folder by clicking it, click on Organize and then click on Export Bookmarks to HTML file

Comment: Are you sure this still works? I just tried it on Chrome v41 and didn't work

Comment: @nixda I'm using dev, which has the new bookmarks manager - which has export which works only for all the bookmarks, not the one specific to a folder. Can't say about stable version..

Answer (score -2):

There are more efficient ways, better ways and so on and so on... but I think in this case the *easiest* way is just sufficient. No Text Editing.

Here are the steps:

1. Open Google Chrome
2. Navigate to bookmarks manager
3. Export to html file
4. Download and install srware iron (or other chrome based browser)
5. Open iron (do NOT log in!)
6. Navigate to bookmarks manager
7. Import from html file
8. Now manually delete all things you don't need in you end file
9. Export edited setting as html file
10. You're ready to go!